# IBM ClearCase Error Out of Stack Space

Tags: clearcase

Getting Out Of Stack Space error while trying to move files from my DEV folder to REL folder. Using VB script to move files was working fine before, but started to get the error recently.

Comment: What version of ClearCase are you using? Is this a dynamic or snapshot view? On which OS are you? On which OS the ClearCase server is?

Comment: using snapshot view, version  ClearCase 7.1.1.1 (Windows NT 6.1)

Answer (score 1):

Since ClearCase 7.1.1 dates [from Dec. 2009](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025381), you might be hit by an old [(Visual Studio 6) Out-Of-Stack-Space error 28 from that time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264523(v=vs.60).aspx).
The causes for that error range from:

- too many active Function, Sub, or Property procedure calls.
- local variables require more local variable space than is available
- too many fixed-length strings
- too many nested DoEvents function calls
- code triggered an event cascade

Try and simplify your script to see if the issue persists, then add back in the code your removed during the simplification process, in order to determine what part causes the error.

Note that [CC7.1.X is in EOS (End Of support) since Sept. 2014](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?q45=V671527C84843Z95) (two years ago). Upgrading (both from WNT, and from CC7.1.X) might be a good idea, if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for ur advice :)

Comment: @VenkateshprasadVenkatesh You are welcome. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer